# Is $\forall x (P(x) \iff Q(x))$ equivalent to $(\forall x P(x)) \iff (\forall x Q(x))$

Tags: logic, solution-verification

The question is whether the statements $\forall x (P(x) \iff Q(x))$  and $(\forall x P(x)) \iff (\forall xQ(x))$ are logically equivalent.

My thinking is that that they are not because of the example ($x$ a real number)

$P(x): x^2 < 0$

$Q(x): x^2 \geq 1$.

Now we have $P(x)$ is always false, so $\forall xP(x)$ if false. Also $\forall xQ(X)$ is also false (since for some $x$ Q(x) is false). That means that $(\forall x P(x)) \iff (\forall xQ(x))$ is true. But here there is an $x$ such that $P(x)$ is false and $Q(x)$ is true.

Does this example work? Is there a more obvious example or another way to prove that the two are not equivalent?

Comment: You are correct in your intuition and your proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT:** (For a simpler example)

Consider $M$ to be a structure in the relevant language whose universe is $\{0,1\}$ and let $P=\{0\}$ and $Q=\{1\}$.

Now you can show that only one of the statement is true in $M$.

Comment: So you are saying that $P(x)$ is always true and $Q(x)$ is always false?

Comment: No. Relations with one variable are essentially subsets of the universe. I'm telling you which elements in $M$ satisfy $P$ and which satisfy $Q$. If you want, replace $0$ by $a$ and $1$ by $b$.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks.

Comment: I did not understand. can you show elaborate the passages ?

Comment: @user305883: Have you tried applying the definitions to check the truth value of each of the sentences?

Comment: Probably where I got mistaken: p={0}, q={1} ∀(()⟺()) would be false: (0)⟺(1) evaluates to F ⟺ T  so the formula is false.   (∀())⟺(∀()) : P(0)⟺(1) evaluates to F ⟺ T so the formula is false.

Comment: @user305883 Why is $\forall xQ(x)$ true?

Comment: @AsafKaragila because Q(1) evaluates to true. There is one value assigned, *1*, so for any interpretations of *x * I ∀() I get true.
do I make a mistake in interpreting how to assign values from the Universe {0,1} ?

Comment: @user305883: So, why is $\forall xP(x)$ false? After all, $P(0)$ is true...

Comment: could you explain why?

Comment: @user305883: I think you need to revise the definition of truth.